# When i make Android run file can't be read

Tags: libgdx

Hi i have problem with android run my project in LibGDX, in desktop run works everythink all right. My working direktory in desktop is in location "ProjecktGKLibGDX\android\assets" (so the same as android default), when i run projekt in android aplikation, it crash with error than one of the file can't be found (menu.png). I use atlas for the Sprites, it work like this:
atlas= new TextureAtlas("Menu.atlas");
and this is my atlas file :

```
menu.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
EXIT
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 418
  size: 900, 415
  orig: 900, 415
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
LOAD
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 900, 415
  orig: 900, 415
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1

menu2.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
PLAY
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 418
  size: 900, 415
  orig: 900, 415
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
SAVE
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 900, 415
  orig: 900, 415
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1

menu3.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
open_menu
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Atlas and png images are in the same folder ("ProjecktGKLibGDX\android\assets"), soo android can read Atlas file but can't read png files.

```
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: menu.PNG
        Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: menu.PNG (Internal)
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: menu.PNG
```

Comment: Why does the error report missing `menu.` **PNG** instead of `menu.` **png**?

Comment: i read in difrent post that android can read it like PNG soo,  to one test i change this, but it dosean work with PNG and png i also try to change name "menu.atlas" to "menu.pack" and then in android run, he can't find file  menu.pack, and in desktop run it work always

Comment: Watch for letter cases. On windows i.e. OS doesn't make difference and will load the file ignoring the letter case. But on linux based systems, as android you have to match letter cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message "Error reading file: menu.PNG (Internal)" implies it might have to do with using the LibGDX file type "Internal". If you create a TextureAtlas with a string it automatically creates the atlas using the "Internal" file type.
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html#TextureAtlas-java.lang.String-

On desktop the Internal and Local file types do essentially the same thing so these don't matter, but on Android they are different. You can read more about the different file types here:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

Try changing the line:

```
atlas= new TextureAtlas("Menu.atlas");
```

To:

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.local("Menu.atlas"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It happens because menu.PNG doesn't exist. Check your assets and make sure that your file name is "menu.PNG".